# State is getting reset everytime the component is opened

Tags: angular, ngrx-store-4.0

I have the following reducer:

```
export function partnerReducer(state = PartnerState.getInitialState(),  action: Actions): PartnerState {
 console.log('state', state)
 switch (action.type) {
  case STORE_PARTNER:
    return { ...state, partner: action.payload }
  case RESET_PARTNER:
    console.log('calling this')
    return { ...state, partner: action.payload }
  default:
    return state
 }
}
```

This is the `PartnerState` class

```
export default class PartnerState {
partner: Partner

static getInitialState() {
  const partnerState = new PartnerState()
  partnerState.partner = new Partner()

  return partnerState
 }
}
```

This is the code in the component

```
 this.store.select(getPartner).subscribe((partner: Partner) => {
  let retrievedPartner = partner
  console.log('retrievedPartner', retrievedPartner)
  if (Util.isNull(retrievedPartner) || Util.isEmpty(retrievedPartner)) {
    console.log('retrieved partner is null')
    this.getPartner()
  } else {
    console.log('got a partner')
    this.partner = retrievedPartner
    this.getPartnerUsers()
  }
 })
}
```

`this.getPartner()` calls a service and retrieves the partner. On success, the partner is stored in store like this `this.store.dispatch(new StorePartnerAction(response))`

But whenever I refresh the route in the browser, I get this response:

```
state 
    Object { partner: {} }
retrievedPartner 
    Object {  }
retrieved partner is null
state 
   Object { partner: {} }
retrievedPartner 
   Object { ... partner object}
got a partner
```

Expected response on page reload:

```
 state 
    Object { partner: ...Partner Params }
retrievedPartner 
    Object { ... partner object}
got a partner
```

Comment: What's the expected response?

Comment: I have updated the question with the expected response